# Google auto populate address without map in quasar vue issue

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, google-api, autocomplete, quasar

I'm using quasar framework.
And VueGmaps package for autopopulate adress, which i installed it using
**npm install vue-gmaps --save**

```
<script>
  import Vue from "vue";
  import VueGmaps from 'vue-gmaps'
  mounted() {
     this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
     (this.$refs.autocomplete),
     { 
       type: ['geocode'],
       componentRestrictions: { country: 'NZ' }
     }
  )
  this.autocomplete.addListener('changed_place',()=>{
    let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace()
    let ac = place.address_components
    let city = ac
    this.city = city
    this.cities.push(ac[0]['short_name'].concat(', ',ac[2]['short_name']))

    console.log(this.city);
  })
 },
  </script>

     <teamplate>
       <q-input              
          ref="autocomplete"              
          v-model="user.address"              
          filled              
          label="Physical Address"              
          hint="Your permanent address"              
          :rules="[val => !!val || 'This field is required.']"              
          />
     </template>
```

I’m getting error google is not defined in console. please check screenshot below

[image]

I want this to give suggestion of address when anyone types anything in the textfield & take the city, state, street from the address
without displaying map.

can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I remove the the vue-google-autocomplete package.

I found out that i was giving reference instead of id, I guess google map api only work with id attribute.

Here is the solution that worked for me without using any packages
it might help some one.
<q-input
ref=“autocomplete”
filled
v-model=“user.address”
label=“Physical Address”
for=“address” //id attribute
hint=“Your permanent address”
:rules="[val => !!val || ‘This field is required.’]"
/>

and in mounted

```
mounted() {
  this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
   // (this.$refs.autocomplete),
    (document.getElementById(“address”)),
    {types: [‘geocode’]}
  );
 this.autocomplete.addListener(‘place_changed’, () => {
 let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
 let ac = place.address_components;
 console.log(ac);
 }
});
```